# Knockoffs of the Moki Doorstep

Tags: patent-infringement

This is the patent:

https://patents.google.com/patent/US10155479B2/en?oq=10%2c155%2c479

It appeared in an episode of Shark Tank.

This is the actual product sold on amazon:

[https://www.amazon.com/Rightline-Gear-100660-Original-Shark/dp/B07JMTVP9N/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=moki+doorstep&qid=1663728680&sprefix=moki+%2Caps%2C101&sr=8-3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07JMTVP9N)

This is one knockoff that I can find:

[https://www.amazon.com/Foldable-Breaker-Safety-Hammer-Universal/dp/B09Q2ZT6BV/ref=sr_1_4?keywords=moki+doorstep&qid=1663728680&sprefix=moki+%2Caps%2C101&sr=8-4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09Q2ZT6BV)

The only real difference between the Moki Doorstep and the knockoff is that the knockoff is foldable.

Why isn't the knockoff infringing upon the Moki Doorstep?

Comment: Do you know that it is not a licensee of the patent ?

Comment: I do not know that. However, why license out your invention when you are already manufacturing and selling it yourself?

Comment: @BigCatPublicSafetyAct If the foldable would cost more, or substantially the same, I'd say: Maybe because it's cheaper to sign a piece of paper and get free money than deal with manufacturing, sale administration, shipping, implied warranties, returns, refunds etc. But the more compact solution is 3 times less. I'd find it extremely unlikely the patent holder would have licensed for say, $2 a unit for the mockup company to manufacture for a dollar or two, then turn maybe a dollar profit while cannibalizing the original product that could probably turn +$10-15 profit each sale.

Comment: Amazon is the new flee market...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an infringement. However, unless a patent infringement notification is served on Amazon and the mockup company (or less plausibly the buyers), the infringement would not provide for a basis of a suit unless the fact is established by the of-jurisdiction court that the infringer knew about the invention, and willfully infringed. (see also the question: ["Can you safely do anything without infringing patents?"](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/84526/can-you-safely-do-anything-without-infringing-patents/84528#84528))

Although the mockup company may obtain a patent on the improvement if filed for, and found non-obvious, but that would not protect them from the infringement of the cited U.S. patent (#10,155,479 B2). It would merely mean that if the manufacturer of the original also wanted to start a foldable one, now they would need to deal with getting a license from the mockup company if they would have obtained a patent on the foldable invention.

Comment: This is a good answer, but perhaps you could try to avoid using legalese.

Comment: @EricS Thank you for the feedback; I'll include a less legalese summary from now on.

Comment: Even though the answer is accepted, there is nothing keeping you from editing it if you want to add some polish. Thanks for the contribution.