# Is this a successful design around the Moki Doorstep?

Tags: patent-infringement

This a continuation question arising out of the question: [Knockoffs of the Moki Doorstep](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/24940/knockoffs-of-the-moki-doorstep)

This is the patent:

https://patents.google.com/patent/US10155479B2/en?oq=10%2c155%2c479

It appeared in an episode of Shark Tank.

This is the actual product sold on amazon:

[https://www.amazon.com/Rightline-Gear-100660-Original-Shark/dp/B07JMTVP9N/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=moki+doorstep&qid=1663728680&sprefix=moki+%2Caps%2C101&sr=8-3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07JMTVP9N)

This is a different design that I found on Amazon:

[https://www.amazon.com/TOOENJOY-Universal-Foldable-Supports-Rooftop/dp/B08R86H9CR/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=moki+doorstep&qid=1663951310&sprefix=moki+doo%2Caps%2C116&sr=8-3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08R86H9CR)

Would this be a successful design around or is it infringement?

Comment: What analysis have you done? Add a list of features from the claims or at least include the independent claims in your question to make it easier to answer. Are there specific limitations in the claims that you suspect the other device has avoided?

Comment: @PatentosPite This one has a different configuration.

Comment: @BigCatPublicSafetyAct Correct, my apologies! This is under the same abstract idea, but the design may very well be outside of the scope of the patent, and potentially so distant from it to not be obvious making it eligible for a patent facially.